# Mounting options with Systemd Mount Units

Tags: systemd, mount, fstab, units

I used to use the fstab file for mounting drives. This time i wanted to use Units instead and created a .mount file. However i wonder how i would set a file system check option and umask settings there.
For example in a fstab file you would do that by adding (just as an example)
`umask=000 0 1`
I'm not sure if i can just use the same options in a .mount file?

Comment: Check the `DirectoryMode=` option, mentioned in `man systemd.mount`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, `umask=000 0 1` is not a mount option; it's **three** separate fields, only the first of which contains mount options.

1. The `umask=000` part is the actual option list; it *usually* can be directly used in systemd's `Options=` parameter. All options that would be passed to the filesystem work the same way as they do in fstab. The only exception are pseudo-options such as `user` or `X-mount.mkdir` that would make sense to the 'mount' program rather than the filesystem itself.

   ```
   [Mount]
   Options=rw,fmask=0133,dmask=022
   ```
2. The `0` that follows it is the "dump" field, an indicator for the ancient dump(8) backup tool. It is not used when mounting (rather, 'dump' reads fstab on its own), so there is no systemd equivalent.
3. The final `1` is the "fsck pass" field, used to activate fsck for this filesystem. The systemd equivalent for this is an explicit dependency on the fsck service instance:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Requires=systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2dpartlabel-EFI.service
   After=systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2dpartlabel-EFI.service
   ```

   Use `systemd-escape --path --template=systemd-fsck@.service /dev/foo` to conveniently generate the correct unit name for your device.

If in doubt, add an fstab entry, reload systemd, then use `systemctl cat` to look at the .mount unit that systemd generated for you. (And then continue just using that fstab entry.)

```
# echo "/dev/sdz1 /mnt/movies ext4 umask=077 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl cat mnt-movies.mount
```